# Facebook Send Dialog no longer offers "picture" as parameter?

Tags: facebook, url

I recently built a website which included a way to send "Postcards" via the Facebook Send Dialog. Using the URL outlined in Facebook developer docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/), four links on the site would open up the send dialog, each with a different picture depending on what the user wanted.

Suddenly, this month, the pictures are no longer attached and the parameter is no longer shown as an option in the docs. Any idea why? Is there a way I can get around the issue?